# scrape a web made with angular

Tags: angularjs, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a web made with Angularjs, using java.
I use Selenium and a ChromeDriver to tramping the web, and, to know the next step I use devtools of Chrome.

In a 'traditional' website I can guess easily the id of the item or where a button goes, looking in Elements or Source tag but, how can I do it in a web made with angular?
I mean, where I can found the id, href property or where a button goes in an angular web? Can I find it using devtools of chrome or I need to install something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what your doing is probably illegal.

But to give you the benefit of the doubt, and guess that you are doing to a website that belongs to you but you didn't write, or don't have the code, or you have permission from the website owner you have two options.

> 1. Extension.

You can use [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en), which lets you inspect your AngularJS in the chrome debugger tools.

Then you can check where the `ng-click` leads to, and look for that function on the scope.

> 2. Console.

Select the element you are interested in inspecting, and since `$0` returns the current selected element in the DOM you can write in the console:

```
angular.element($0).scope()
```

which will return you an object with all the data on the current scope.

Note that you might have to go up the $parent, to find the function you are looking for.

P.S. if you are looking for how to do the same thing in Angular, you can use [the following extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/augury/elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd?hl=en) (thanks @user1767316) or in the console `ng.probe($0).componentInstance`

Comment: Thanks Rabbi, I'm testing a web in my new job which I've not written.

Comment: Ok, hope I helped. I would be grateful if you could accept the answer since I am building my reputation here on SO.

Comment: The suggested extention seems to target angularjs. For angular applications rather try [augury](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/augury/elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd?hl=en)

Comment: @user1767316 the question has a tag of AngularJS, and the answer was written before angular was a thing. I edited my answer to clarify that I am indeed talking about AngularJS

Comment: @RabbiShukiGur how is that illegal?

Comment: @Alator Scraping a web site that doesn't belong to you usually stems from the wrong reasons. That is why I said `probably`.